# How to implement AirPrint button on iPhone/iPad/iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins, airprint

I implemented an application for iPhone / iPad, developed in Sencha Touch and Phonegap. In previous tests, when the application could display on Safari (not. IPA), there was a possibility of printing using the AirPrint button that the browser has. I lost this button to generate the ios installer. Has someone has implemented something like this? I think there is a plugin called print, but I'd like more guidance.

I saw [this plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin/READEME.md), but it does not work for me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -2):

Not sure I get your question; but the standard approach I take is

```
if (![UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]) {
   .. config UI right
```

to figure out if a print dialogue makes sense. And if it is; the standard apple code (e.g. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67176-airprint-tutorial-simple-print-file-30-lines-of-code.html) will do splendidly ?

And use the usual break out to objective-C from Phonegap - which means it is iOS specific.

Thanks,

Dw.